# Whether it's correct to say he is easy to get angry?

Tags: grammar, tough-movement

My confusion is that if there are any grammatical rules or limitation on the logical subject of infinitive, adjective-wise maybe?

I know these work:

> He is happy to do something
> something is easy to do

How about?

> he is easy to get angry

I know most people would say he  gets angry easily. I just wonder if there are fixed logic behind as in sentences of the first kind being used to describe how a person feel about doing something and the second for judgment of something .

Comment: Do you mean that it’s easy to get him angry or that he gets angry easily?

Comment: I mean the second one and  I did try the sentence he is easy to anger.

Comment: He is quick to anger.

Comment: @WeatherVane Please stop posting answers in comments.

Answer (score 3):

- *He is easy to get angry.*

is grammatical, but it doesn't mean the same as

- *He gets angry easily.*

*Get angry* just means 'become angry',
but *get `X` angry*, with some person `X` named, means 'make `X` become angry'.

With an extra participant, *get* becomes a causative verb, not just an inchoative -- it means 'cause to become', not just 'become'.

OK, that's one construction; now for the *easy* construction. *Easy*, like *tough, hard, a cinch, difficult, simple,* and many similar predicates, undergoes the minor rule called *Tough*-Movement, which relates two sentences by "raising" the object of the verb in the complement clause to become the subject of the main clause:

- *(For Bill) To explain **the missing statue** was tough.*
  === *tough*-movement ===>
- ***The missing statue** was tough (for Bill) to explain.*

The thing about *tough*-movement is that it applies to the **Object** of the downstairs clause (*this problem*), **not** the subject (*Bill*, with or without the complementizer *for*)

- *This problem was hard *for Bill* to solve.*
- ****Bill** was hard to solve this problem*

and that it only applies to **certain** predicates. Other, similar, predicates produce ungrammatical sentences.

- *This problem was hard/easy to solve.*
- *This problem was impossible to solve.*
- **This problem was possible to solve.*
- **This problem was probable/improbable to solve.*

So, that's why *He is easy to get angry* doesn't mean *he gets angry easily*; it already means something else.

Comment: Agreed. Another example, closer to the OP's: "This problem was hard/easy to get right", which is grammatical and means "To get this problem right was hard/easy".

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** As the explanation from CaGEL is very technical and not so easy to understand, I will add here a simplified summary.

*Easy* can only be followed by infinitives which lack not their subject, but
a) their object:

- She is easy to please [it is easy to please *her*].

b) the object of the preposition they are accompanied by:

- He is easy to get along with [it is easy to get along with *him*].

So your sentence:

> He is easy to get angry.

is possible but not with the meaning you intend. To miss its object, *get angry* needs to be **transitive**, so what this sentence is saying is that

> It is easy to get ***him*** angry.

*He is easy to get angry* does not license the intransitive use of the verb *get*, so *He gets angry easily* or *It is easy for him to get angry* are the correct ways to convey the meaning you intend.

*If you are not interested in the grammatical explanation of CaGEL, please ignore the rest.*

---

Your second example is an instance of what [CaGEL](https://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/languages-linguistics/grammar-and-syntax/cambridge-grammar-english-language) calls *hollow infinitive construction* (see p. 1246), whereas the first and third sentence would be cases of *ordinary infinitive construction*. On p. 65, it says:

> There are non-finite clauses in which a non-subject NP is missing:
>
> - John is easy [ to please_] ( where the missing object of ***please*** is understood as ***John***) or
> - This idea is worth [giving some thought to _] (where the complement of the preposition ***to*** is
>   understood as this ***idea***).
>
> Clauses of this kind we call ***hollow clauses***. [Opposed to the ***ordinary non-finite clauses*** from which the subject is missing]

As for ***easy***, it *does not license ordinary constructions*, it can only be combined with hollow infinitives, according to the same grammar. CaGEL makes this point saying:

> For many of the predicative adjectives <sup>[of which ***easy*** is an example]</sup> an infinitival internal complement ***must always be of the
> hollow type***. Some of them, however, license *ordinary* as well as *hollow complements*, and there is then the potential for ambiguity:
>
> - i They are ready to use_. [hollow]
> - ii They are ready to depart. [ordinary]
> - iii They are ready to eat. [ambiguous]

If you understand this explanation of this ambiguity, you will understand better, by contrast, how ***easy*** works, too. CaGEL says:

> In [i] ***use*** is ***transitive***: *the missing object is recovered from the antecedent **they***, while
> the user is not explicitly indicated.
> In [ii] ***depart*** is *intransitive*, with ***they*** antecedent for
> *the missing subject*.
> ***Eat*** in [iii] is a *dual-transitivity* verb, so that ***they*** can be *antecedent for either a missing object*
> ( cf. **The jam tarts are ready to eat**_) *or the missing subject* ( cf . **The guests are ready to
> eat**).

As you can see, transitivity is important with such structures. Now CaGEL makes an assertion that differentiates *ready* from *easy*, which is in fact the answer to your question:

> ***Ready*** *may be contrasted with, for example,* ***easy***, where *we have hollow*
>
> - This knife is easy to cut with_,
>
> *but not ordinary*
>
> - *This knife is easy to cut. (p. 1248)

It may be expressed in a slightly vague way, but it basically affirms that ***easy* cannot combine with a non-finite infinitival clause from which the subject is missing**.

Let's look at your sentences:

> 1. He is happy to do something.

*To do something* is an **ordinary complement** of the predicative adjective ***happy***. In the non-finite clause *to do something*, ***do*** already has the object ***something***, so the part missing is the subject, which is provided by the antecedent ***He***.

> 2. Something is easy to do.

That's the hollow structure with the missing object of ***do*** provided by the entencedent ***something***.

> 3. He is easy to get angry.

For the meaning you wish to convey, this sentence is incorrect, as ***easy*** can only be used with constructions that miss an object, as explained in CaGEL. Therefore, your sentence means *It is easy to get **him** angry.* But this is not the meaning you want to convey. The correct way to say it is:

> He gets angry easily.

Comment: No, the adverb probably follows: *He gets angry easily.*  Your sources are nearly impeccable, but John's answer is much easier to read and understand.

Comment: I agree with what you say. I will edit.